# Sorting array of collections

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have an array storing 3 merged collections:

```
public function answer() {
        $interview = Interview::find(1);

        $videoQuestions = $interview->VideoQuestions()->get();
        foreach ($videoQuestions as $vq) {
            $vq->type = 'video';
        }

        $textQuestions = $interview->TextQuestions()->get();
        foreach ($textQuestions as $tq) {
            $tq->type = 'text';
        }

        $uploadQuestions = $interview->UploadQuestions()->get();
        foreach ($uploadQuestions as $uq) {
            $uq->type = 'upload';
        }

        $questions = collect($videoQuestions);
        $questions = $questions->merge($textQuestions);
        $questions = $questions->merge($uploadQuestions);

        $questions->sortBy('order_position');
        dd($questions);
    }
```

The ->sortBy is not working as I assume it doesn't work on an array of collections.

This is what I have:
[image]

But I really just want it to be a merged collection not an array inside the collection.

Each `VideoQuestion` or `TextQuestion` has an `order_position` field that I would like to sort by.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing  collection is a class containing an array of elements with special methods to filter sort, docs:

> The Illuminate\Support\Collection class provides a fluent, convenient
>   wrapper for working with arrays of data.

The [sortBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sortby) method returns a sorted collection (it does not apply to the item it has):

```
$collection = collect([
    ['name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200],
    ['name' => 'Chair', 'price' => 100],
    ['name' => 'Bookcase', 'price' => 150],
]);

$sorted = $collection->sortBy('price');

$sorted->values()->all();

/*
    [
        ['name' => 'Chair', 'price' => 100],
        ['name' => 'Bookcase', 'price' => 150],
        ['name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200],
    ]
*/
```

So you should have something like:

```
$questions = $questions->sortBy('order_position');
dd($questions);
```

Comment: Perfect! I simply needed to change `$questions->sortBy('order_position');` to `$questions = $questions->sortBy('order_position');` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This could be an alternative:

```
$interview = Interview::find(1)->with(['VideoQuestions',
                                       'TextQuestions', 
                                       'UploadQuestions', 
                                       'Questions' => function($query){
                                           $query->orderBy('order_position', 'asc');
                                       }])->get();
```

Define the relationships and make a table Questions that holds an order_position that you can sort on instead of each table.